# Facebook open graph - Use object name as title in the Recent Activity Log

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have the action name "shot" and the object named "GIF".

The story shows correctly on timeline:

```
"Keepwalking shot a GIF"
```

But on recent activity logs shows:

```
"Keepwalking shot a This is my new Gif"
```

How can i make so its shows GIF (the name of the object) not the page title.

Comment: I think you've misnamed your verb, did you make the action 'shot a' instad of 'shot'?

Comment: Been fussing with this for days, Facebook documentation and UI is so bad...

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to the OG object URL? Check what og:title value is being rendered.

Use Facebook's Open Graph debugger to see what FB sees when it crawls your object:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug